# What and where does the info.fieldASTs(resolve parameter) come from?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have read a lot of resources about graphql but somehow I need help to understand graphqls' resolve parameters. here is the code(from fullstack react):

```
resolve(source, args, context, info) {
 let includeFriends = false;
const selectionFragments = info.fieldASTs[0].selectionSet.selections;
const userSelections = selectionFragments.filter((selection) => {
return selection.kind === 'InlineFragment' && selection.typeCondition.\
name.value === 'User';
})
```

would appreciate someone share some resources about graphql's resolve function, what are these-> (source, args, context, info) parameters? and where they come from? and how can I see fieldASTs on the code? I look at the schema.json file, and cannot see where it came from, how can I see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `resolve` functions are to return the data for each **field** requested in the GraphQL query.

> what are these-> (source, args, context, info) parameters?

- source - The object resolved from the field on the parent type
- args - The GraphQL arguments for that field
- context - An arbitrary contextual value that can be passed in to GraphQL
- info - a.k.a. the "resolve info" has *everything* you could every want to know about the GraphQL query (its AST, the fragments, variables, etc), and the schema being executed (field names, types, etc).

> and where they come from? and how can I see fieldASTs on the code?

This depends which GraphQL implementation you are using. I'll assume you are using [the Node.js reference implenatation](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) by Facebook. Most developers probably don't need to look at the resolve info to resolve their data, as it mostly deals with the internals. But if you want to understand how this is generated, you'll need to read the source code. [Here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/execution/execute.js#L594) is where the resolve info is created during the executing phase of GraphQL.

To generate your own `schema.json`, you can use the `printSchema` function imported from `graphql/utilities`:

```
import { graphql }  from 'graphql'
import { introspectionQuery, printSchema } from 'graphql/utilities'

/*
  generates json of our schema for use by relay
 */
export default function (schema) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(schema, introspectionQuery).then(result => {
      if (result.errors) {
        console.error(`ERROR introspecting schema: ${result.errors}`)
        reject(new Error(result.errors))
      } else {
        resolve({ json: result, graphql: printSchema(schema) })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: i was reading this http://pcarion.com/2015/09/27/GraphQLResolveInfo/ and he has generated a fieldAST from schema.json? how can I do it in mine?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a snippet for how to generate the `schema.json`.

Comment: how is the source parameter created? is it from the root query? how is it passed there?

Comment: "source" is the value returned from the resolver on the parent field. The resolvers are called in a "waterfall" from parent to child. Suppose you have a field called `user` of object type `User`. The `User` has a `name` field. When the user resolves and returns an object, then it's children resolve. So the `name` resolver is called by graphql, and it passes "source" as that same object that the `user` resolver returned.